# BB 10 cascade Disable physical back button on blackberry classic

Tags: blackberry-10

Need a help i'm using native sdk (Momentics).
I want to disable the physical "Back" button on blackberry classic device throughout my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the back button override the code with

```
shortcuts: [
    DeviceShortcut {
        type: DeviceShortcuts.BackTap
        onTriggered: {
            //do somethings
        }
    }
]
```

However it is useful performs some action after the click of the back button.

For more info:
[BlackBerry Documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/device_comm/input/classic_keys.html)

Comment: I have tried as u have suggested but it seems not working.
Do i need to add empty implementation ?

Comment: Yes. Try to add empty implementation.